# Hiding Android Keyboard 'Settings' key programmatically

Tags: android

I want to hide the Android Keyboard <kbd>Settings</kbd> key programmatically. Can anyone suggest how one should approach for it. At Present I am overriding the `onKeyDown()` method and getting the event so that the settings event can be `disabled/hidden`. But this doesn't work. How can I make it possible. I need to achieve this because in my app I lock a screen and user has to enter a code to unlock it. But when he is entering the lock code through the Android soft keyboard there's this settings key through which a user can come out of the lock screen. So I need a way to *hide* or *disable* this key on the Android Soft keyboard somehow.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: You know the user could also press home, right? Or receive a phone call? Or go to a notification?

Comment: No offence but this sounds like a really annoying app. You want to make the entire phone locked (unusable) until the victi- er, user inputs a code? What if they've forgotten it, or just don't have it for whatever reason? You *have* to let them get out of your app in some way.

Comment: This acts as a security purpose for the user to misuse by the others. Well i have taken care of the password protection for user.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I want to do the exact same thing.

Comment: Any update for this?